# Not initialised variable after casting

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying to cast class, but something is wrong. I was trying `static_cast<>`, `dynamic_cast<>` but still im getting errors. I need one array with 2 types of classes.

```
class user
{
  int value;
  user(int valueInit) 
  {
     value = valueInit;
  };

  int getValue()
  {
     return value;
  }

};

class premium : public user
{
  int premiumValue;
  premium(int valueInt, int premiumValueInit) 
  {
      value = valueInt;
      premiumValue = premiumValueInit;
  };
};
```

And here is main code in `main()` function

```
user fUser(10);
premium fPremium(20, 5);

premium *array = new premium[2];

(user)array[0] = u1;
array[1] = p1;

cout << "Value: " << array[0].getValue() << endl; //incorrect/random value
    cout << "Value: " << array[1].getValue() << endl; //correct value
```

Usually I use java, so I have huge problems with c++. I know what I should do but I dont know how.

Comment: Programming by guessing, huh

Comment: In c++? Sometimes ;) I've more experience with java syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The why**

The problem with your cast, `(user)array[0] = u1` is that it is, theoretically, equivalent to the code below:

```
{
  user unnamed_instance = array[0];
       unnamed_instance = u1;
}
```

In `(T)a = b;` an unnamed temporary will be created having type `T` which is than initialized with the value of `b`. You are assigning to this unnamed temporary, not to `a`.

<sup>**Note**: In this case [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1090079) takes place, ie. the value in `array[0]`, which has type `premium`, will be sliced into a `user`.</sup>

---

**The solution**

If you'd like to treat the value in `array[0]` as being of type `user` without introducing a temporary you will need to use either pointers or references. The below will correctly assign `u1` to `array[0]` as if `array[0]` was of type `user`.

```
// using a reference 

static_cast<user&> (array[0]) = u1;
```

```
// using a pointer

user * ptr = static_cast<user*> (&array[0]);
      *ptr = u1;
```

Comment: Works great, I know now what I was doing wrong: `static_cast<user*>(array[0]) = u1;` It's been a long time since I've used pointers and reference. Thanks.

Comment: anyone wanna explain the downvote that just got cast?

Comment: If `array[0]` is of type `user`, then it is simply impossible to store a `premium` in it.  Both of Filip's suggestions slice the `premium` down to `user`, but then there is no way to get the `premium` back.

Comment: The original question doesn't say anything about slicing, and he is creating an array of `premium` (not an array of `user`).

Comment: You say "lvalue in array[0]" but that is not correct usage. An lvalue is a category of **expression**, not a property of an object.  The expression `array[0]` is an lvalue because it designates an object. Where you wrote *lvalue* you meant *object*.

Comment: BTW, OP's classes only have private constructors so they can't be created, and since there is no default constructor, you can't even dynamically allocate an array of them. Further, a `premium` can't be created because `base` has no default constructor and it does not pass anything to `base`'s constructor. So there must be more to this story than we're seeing.

Comment: "value yield in the expression array[0] is an lvalue" - this isn't right. An lvalue is a category of expression, not a category of value. See section [basic.lval] of the Standard.   But this has nothing to do with OP's question now.

Comment: OP seems happy with your answer, I guess he will post again when he comes to add another class derived from `base`..:)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm in no mood to answer to nitpicking, the intent with the sentence was clear (and not using Standard terms was to keep it easier for a novice (as is what we are dealing with) to understand). Please submit your own answer to aid OP if you are certain that this will lead to follow-up questions. For your sake I will update the answer.